# Displaying two Google Graphs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, graph

I am trying to display 2 Google Graphs on my web page. Currently I can display the one without a problem.

The trouble comes in when I'm trying to display the other graph under the first one.

my front end code looks like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: 'MindYourMatterDash.aspx/GetData',
                data: '{}',
                dataType: "json",
                success:
                    function (response) {
                        drawVisualization(response.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        alert("Please Contact Support with the following code in the subject :404 graph");
                    }
            });
        })

        function drawVisualization(dataValues) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Column Name');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Column Value');

            for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, dataValues[i].Value]);
            }

            new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
                draw(data, { title: "Broken PTP's Graph" });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: 'MindYourMatterDash.aspx/GetDataFollowing',
                data: '{}',
                dataType: "json",
                success:
                    function (response) {
                        drawVisualization(response.d);
                    },
                error: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    alert("Please Contact Support with the following code in the subject :404 graph");
                }
            });
        })

        function drawVisualization2(dataValues) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Column Name');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Column Value');

            for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, dataValues[i].Value]);
            }

            new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('FollowGraph')).
                draw(data, { title: "Follow Ups Graph" });
        }


    </script>
```

and the code behind the page:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<Data> GetData()
    {
        string cat = "";
        int val = 0;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        cQuery _GraphInfo = new cQuery();
        _GraphInfo.Sqlstring = "SQL Statement";

        DataSet ds = _GraphInfo.SelectStatement();

        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        List<Data> datalist = new List<Data>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            cat = dr[0].ToString();
            val = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]);
            datalist.Add(new Data(cat, val));

        }
        return datalist;
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<Data> GetDataFollowing()
    {
        string cat = "";
        int val = 0;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        cQuery _GraphInfo2 = new cQuery();
        _GraphInfo2.Sqlstring = "SQL Statement";

        DataSet ds = _GraphInfo2.SelectStatement();

        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        List<Data> datalist2 = new List<Data>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            cat = dr[0].ToString();
            val = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]);
            datalist2.Add(new Data(cat, val));

        }
        return datalist2;
    }
```

Currently when this code runs it loads the first graph and then replaces the first graph with the second one instead of loading it into the second div tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it because of the ajax type:post?

Comment: You always use `document.getElementById('visualization')`, may you need to use different elements for different graphs? Or may you should use `drawVisualization2` somewhere?